# Laravel use string from MySQL as variable

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Good night, I have a code that substitutes the data from the request and displays it, like this:

```
    $client = User::find($data['$id']);
    $execute = 'Send command ';
    $execute .=  $client->id;
    dd($execute);
```

It return

```
^ "Send command 1"
```

Everything is working.
But I want that if I add a variable to the database, for example, like this

```
$client->id
```

, and call it, then I need the code to process it as a variable, and not as a string, how to do this, thanks)

Example:
(inside the variable $cliend in the database will be the following code:

```
$client->id
```

Code:

```
 $client = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->value('id');
    $execute = 'Send command ';
    $execute .=  $client;
    dd($execute);
```

It is necessary that this variable be executed as a variable. and returned its value not from the database, but as in the first example

Comment: If I don't mistake you, you want the put the variable name into the string? Why not just [use \ to escape](https://3v4l.org/jeC2L) as you would anything else as per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)? If `$client` holds a variable, then you can [access it correspondingly](https://3v4l.org/lJK2X)

Comment: I'm trying to make the variable that I got from the database called and return some value to me, and not be returned as a string, for example.
I will write $client->id in the code, it will return the id to me, I want to put this $client->id into the database and when I output this from the database, I want it to be executed and not output as a regular string

Comment: Ok, I mean, I would never suggest to `eval()` untrusted user input but I don't think there is a way to do this using [variables variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) so [use this at your own discretion](https://3v4l.org/tFUgu) - this just means your database design is failing if you're doing this.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and therefore I would recommend you also share your motivation for pursuing this solution. Broadly speaking storing PHP code in a database for later execution is not recommended and in almost all cases there are much better alternatives to solve the given problem

Comment: @apokryfos  Hello, i need this so that the administrator can add a command that will then be sent to the console, while still accepting external variables such as client id.

Comment: @Jaquarh 
Do you can tell me how to make it so that if the query from the database contains not only a variable, but also a regular code that needs to be output as a string, for example,  of a query from the database:
"status $client->id"
It is $client->id that only the variable be converted to a variable, status was passed as a regular string, otherwise the code does not work.
I will be very grateful to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having to store variable names into the database is extremely bad practice although PHP does natively support [variables variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

In your case, I do not see how you could implement this against an object without having to [eval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) some additional code against, assumingly, untrusted user input.

I would first suggest redesigning your database logic to avoid this but if this is necessary or/and your data is controlled then here is a solution:

```
// Your object you want to access the value of
$client = (object) ['id' => 1];

// Data from your SQL statement that stores that variable name
$databaseValue = '$client->id';

// Eval and store result as variable
eval("\$value = {$databaseValue};");

// Result: Send command 1
echo "Send command {$value}";
```

See it working over at [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/tFUgu)

---

Some additional thoughts, you could potentially use regex to capture that the stored data is indeed a variable and only grab the first match.

```
^\$(?:[a-z]||[A-Z])\S+
```

You can see an example of this over on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ITOm1) where we remove any potential bad stuff from the data but this is a very blacklisted approach and you should always look to take a whitelisted approach. Just hoping this helps down the line somewhere else.

For some explanation, please checkout [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gQMqTp/1) where I added some examples how this could be easily escaped and is no way the ultimate solution.

---

Update: Here is another regex you could potentially use to narrow down this even further.

```
(?:\s|^)\$(?:[^\s]+?)(?:[a-z])+(?:->|$)?(?:[a-z]|[A-Z])+
```

Example and explanation can be found over at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jU0ISp/1). PHP example can be found over at [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/JfHGC) (which remember is still never perfect).

Comment: Thanks!
I need this so that the administrator can add a command that will then be sent to the console, while still accepting external variables such as client id.
Thanks again!

Comment: No problem - just try to ensure you take a whitelisted approach when storing the variables - you could perhaps use [regular expressions](https://3v4l.org/KBCsI) to ensure only a variable is passed if not.

Comment: Hm, i try like this, and variable don`t execute
https://3v4l.org/IFcrC
(example from my code)
My mysql query:
status $client->id

Comment: Read the `eval()` you're creating a new variable named `$value` which will contain the variables value. [Use that :)](https://3v4l.org/jgdlc)

Comment: You save my life! Very thanks!!! Thankss!!!

Comment: No problem, best of luck :)